# how to create a service detect new Contact Add

Tags: android, contentobserver

I find a lot of code to detect the noveaux add contacts

for example

```
public class ContactsObserver extends ContentObserver {
private final static String TAG = ContactsObserver.class.getSimpleName();

private Context ctx;
private List<ContactsChangeListener> listeners = new ArrayList<ContactsChangeListener>();

private ContactsObserver(Context ctx) {
    super(new Handler());
    this.ctx = ctx.getApplicationContext();
    ctx.getContentResolver()
        .registerContentObserver(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,  // uri
                false,                                  // notifyForDescendents
                this);                                  // observer
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Contacs change");
    for(ContactsChangeListener l : listeners){
        l.onContactsChange();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
    return false; // set to true does not change anything...
}

public static ContactsObserver register(Context ctx){
    Log.d(TAG, "register");
    return new ContactsObserver(ctx);
}

public void unregister(){
    Log.d(TAG, "unregister");
    ctx.getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(this);
}

public void addContactsChangeListener(ContactsChangeListener l){
    listeners.add(l);
}

public interface ContactsChangeListener{
    void onContactsChange();
}
}
```

but this code is associated with an activity,

I think the application works when open, but I want a service uses ContentObserver

is what replaces the execution of this code

```
getContentResolver()
                .registerContentObserver(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true,
                        new MyCOntentObserver());
```

put in the service  method "OnStart"

Answer (score 0):

Register in service using:

```
getApplication().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true,new MyCOntentObserver());
```